# Cannot Put error in postman..May I know what's the error..I have no problem in post and get request

Tags: node.js, express, joi

/*This is code that used to put request and change the team name
     I don't know what is the question and I try many times and it keeps coming out cannot put error...*/

```
    obj.put('api/team/:number', (req,res)=>{

    const tim = teams.find(t => t.number === parseInt(req.params.number)) 
    if (!tim) 
        res.status(404).send("The team with the given number is not exist!");


    const { error, value } = validationdata(req.body);

    if (error){
        res.send(error + "\nPlease try again!");
        return;
    }

    tim.Team= req.body.Team;
    res.send(tim);

});
function validationdata(nama){

const schema = Joi.object({
        "Team" : Joi.string().min(5).max(20).required()
    });
    //const results = schema.validate(req.body);
    return schema.validate(req.body);
};
```

Comment: put slash `/` like `obj.put('/api/team/:number', (req,res)`

Comment: facing the same problem... could you fix that? I am calling `app.put('/api/contacts/:id', (req, res))` but always having the error `CANNOT PUT` in postman ...